# Access Denied using S3 upload function

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a lambda function with the following policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am calling the `listObjectsV2` without problem but when I want to call the `upload` method I have `ERROR  AccessDenied: Access Denied`

This is my code

```js
const addImage = (name, image) => {
    name = `${Image.getPrefix()}/${name}.${crypto.randomBytes(3).toString('hex')}.${image.originalname.split('.').pop()}`;

    return s3.upload({
        Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_IMAGE,
        ACL: 'public-read',
        Body: image.buffer,
        Key: name
    }).promise()
    .then(result => new Image(result))
}
```

Comment: Share a snippet of your lambda that's uploading.  From the cli I can upload to a bucket with the permissions you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

Using lambda you have to add a policy on the bucket too

https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/access-denied-lambda-s3-bucket/

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountA:role/AccountARole"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::AccountBBucketName/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```